Has the government of Afghanistan clarified what they mean/intend by the ban on 'images of living beings'?
According to VOA, Afghanistan has passed new laws that ban many things including women's voices in many public circumstances and even "images of living beings", which is suspected to be a pretext for banning TV altogether.
Some of that isn't too surprising as they've been cracking down at least on women's presence in the media already. I wonder if there's some mistranslation involved in "images of living beings", or are they really envisaging banning all TV? (AFAICT, that's not totally implausible since they did just that back in their previous reign in the 1990s. Actually, I see they also seem to have banned all internet back then, so possibly smartphones are in their sights too.) Has the government of Afghanistan clarified if they plan to ban all TV again (and/or smartphones etc.) or what is the extent of the ban on "images of living beings"?

somewhat related, at a doctrinal level:  https://www.metmuseum.org/toah/hd/figs/hd_figs.htm

Aniconism has a long history in Islam and is still popular among Sunni fundamentalists. It is likely that "images of living beings" means exactly what it first appears to mean.

@CharlieEvans - True, but so much of what one might see on television involves images of humans or other animals that a complete ban on that may very well just turn into shutting down all television stations. Basically no fictional shows, no nature documentaries, no news or non-fiction with any kind of person presenting...about the most one could do would be a weather report without a weather journalist, but I doubt Afghanistan TV stations currently have much money for interesting weather animations. Or just images of text (but why bother at that point when newspapers/Internet exist?)

@Obie2.0 Yes, it is not uncommon for the proscriptions of religious fundamentalists to be incompatible with a modern lifestyle.

The ban on images isn't just a Muslim thing. It is in the Torah, and it was also fashionable for a time in Christianity.

@SimonCrase And, for a time, in Buddhism (Wikipedia's page on aniconusm).

I’m voting to close this question because this is a "What is the Law" question.  The answer may be sought on "Law" (which accepts questions about Sharia) and possibly on "Islam", again because the foundation of such a law is religious in nature.

@JamesK Disagree. It's not a question about Sharia, but rather about what a bunch of brigands have said.

@Simon, then the experts on Sharia need to say that.  It's still a "what is the law" question.  Questions about "what a bunch of brigands have said" are Off Topic on Politics

Are you specifically interested in whether they're banning TV or what the effect will be on TV? Because neither of the existing answers have much to do with that, so you might want to be clearer about what exactly you're asking. Or would an answer about other images be acceptable?

@JamesK: I can't find a sharia tag on law.SE https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia or islamic-law https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-law or islam https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam There aren't even any questions about afghanistan https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afghanistan for that matter. So I'm not holding my breath on the number of specialists on that over there.

@StuartF: yeah, what was considered to come under the ban so far under "Taliban 2.0" would be acceptable. I don't think the Q is that unclear. Some people like to write their thoughts on just about anything.

To state what might not be obvious, there is always (inevitably) an interpretive gap between the formulation of a law and the implementation of it. A ban on images of living beings is perfectly in line with Islamic religious tenets, and that is almost certainly what the people who wrote that article had in mind. But how it's used in practice will be decided at a lower level, in policy and legal venues. For instance, the Islamic proscription was originally meant to prevent artistic representations — depictions of the Prophet, or historical figures, or artistic idealizations of the human form — on the grounds that such depictions encroach on creative powers that belong to Allah. The courts may ultimately decide that media broadcasts are acceptable so long as they are factual and faithful transmissions of the human form. In other words, typical television fare (dramas, comedies, news broadcast) might be fine, but fantasy, cartoons, and CGI might not be.
What a law 'means' in its writing is often quite different from what it 'means' in its practice. We have to be careful which question we're asking.

Do note that most (all?) other majority-Muslim countries do not have legal proscriptions against showing human and animal images on television, and even the bastions of Sunni and Shia religious conservatism, Saudi Arabia and Iran, have some fictional TV shows, to say nothing of all the things coming out of Egypt or Lebanon, let alone Türkiye. So the opposite interpretation also is clearly at least as much in line with Islamic religious tenets (well, as interpreted in real life, anyway).

And of course... the rule of law is very weak in places like Afghanistan. Whatever "laws" are in place often has absolutely no meaning in practice in places like this.

From what I can tell, Akhundzada [the Taliban supreme leader] can also issue fatwas. I'm guessing that something as impactful as banning TV won't be let to the latitude of lower-level clerics.

Wikipedia says for instance: "On 14 November 2022, he issued orders to the judiciary to fully enforce Hudud and Qisas (corporal) punishments if crimes meet such standards. This led to concern that the widespread usage of flogging, amputation, and stoning as punishments could resume. A week later, twelve people were publicly flogged in Logar Province, in what was seen as an implementation of Akhundzada's order."

But his power might not be absolute, for now https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VC8hL_oRM_A

This "answer" seems to be pure speculation without any facts.

@StuartF: Your "comment" seems to be pure speculation without any facts.

This answer is partly correct though that for some matters like posters [of living beings] on walls, the decision was apparently delegated to provincial/regional leaders https://8am.media/eng/taliban-bans-displaying-images-of-living-beings-on-the-walls-in-herat-province/ It's not easy to see how that level of decentralization would work for TV though. I mean if one province bans TVs but the central TV stations keep emitting it's like the local leaders ban a propaganda tool of the supreme leader...

@JonathanReez: sometimes that's true. The Saudis had trouble enforcing their ban on satellite dishes in the 1990s. OTOH the Taliban which just physically destroyed TVs in the same period probably found a simpler (albeit broader) enforcement mechanism. TBH given that dishes are much more easily visible from the outside, it was probably more a lack of will to enforce in SA.

@StuartF The requirement of Islamic law that images of living beings not be depicted dates to the 600s and has had a profound effect on Islamic art which lacks portraits and pursued a more abstract and decorative path as a result. So, the ban is already there and has been in every country that gives even lip service to Islamic law for basically forever. The hard part is how to interpret this ban in the modern era and the answer accurately sets out the theory behind how it has been applied elsewhere. But religious laws are subject to myriad readings and the Taliban's interpretation is unclear.

TBH, it's hard to make heads or tail about this. I've seen various somewhat contradictory reports of what they actually plan to ban in practice. To make matters slithgly worse, mostly US state-sponsored media like VOA and RFERL cover this topic in English (anymore).
Anyhow, VOA:

October 17, 2024
The Taliban has ordered media in three provinces of Afghanistan to stop airing images of any living being, a drastic step widely criticized by journalism and civil liberty groups.
The order — part of the new morality law — will be implemented across the country, according to Saiful Islam Khyber, a spokesperson for the Ministry for the Propagation of Virtue and the Prevention of Vice. “The law applies to all Afghanistan,” he told the French news agency AFP.

RFERL:

October 22, 2024
Now, the Taliban has expanded the ban on idolatry to include the “production and watching of videos and photos of living things on computers and mobile phones.”
[...] In recent days, Taliban run-media outlets have stopped showing images of living things in some provinces to comply with the new ban. Some TV stations have resorted to audio-only broadcasts.
The Taliban’s Ministry for the Promotion of Virtue and Prevention of Vice said on October 14 that it is gradually implementing the ban.

(It's unclear they're quoting though.)
OTOH, The Week reported (at about the same time--Oct 17) a softer approach (for now):

Even before the new law was announced, Taliban officials in Kandahar were banned from taking photos and videos of living things. "Now it applies to everyone", said the ministry spokesperson. He added that the prohibition is currently "only advice", and the ministry would focus on "convincing people these things are really contrary" to sharia law and "must be avoided”. [...]
Afghan journalists said they have been assured that they would be able to continue their work. One told AFP that the ministry has advised journalists to take photos from further away and film fewer events "to get in the habit".

The last piece is mostly a shorter version of a story from Economic Times from Oct 14.
